# Query optimization and takes less execution time

Tags: performance

CASE-1:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
JOIN B ON B.CustomerID=A.CustomerID
```

CASE-2:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM B) C 
ON C.CustomerID =A.CustomerID
```

Which CASE is efficient ?

Comment: If am not wrong both will have identical execution plan

Comment: dbms dependent... Probably the same performance with most dbms products. No need to confuse yourself and other people reading the code, stick with case 1.

Comment: Please add the tag for the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ..) If you are using Postgres, please add the output of `explain analyze select ...` for both queries. But for any modern DBMS I would assume that both queries are executed in absolutely the same way by the database.

Comment: All my predecessors are right. It probably will result in the same execution plan. But only EXPLAIN plan will tell ya. 

Also! I think your stuck in the thinking pattern of procedural languages. SQL is a description of the problem, not how it can be solved(not completly true, but it helps at the beginning a lot)

Answer (score 0):

Please run `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and run one of your queries and check the number of pages beeing read in your `message` tab.

A lower execution time doesn't mean that it was more efficient, there are other dependencies like what else was running at the same time in the background?
With number of pages read you can be sure which query uses more or less amount of actual work.

Also have a look at the execution plans, they might be the same...